# UIPageViewController with custom transition Style

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am building an application for iOS which contains a `UIPageViewController`, displaying a couple of content pages.

By default, there are two kinds of transitions:

1. `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`
2. `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

They are pretty cool, but I would like to provide a custom Transition Animation. Is it even possible to "plug in" custom animations? Or is one required to implement a very own Page View Controller?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to stick with any of those transitions, or just create your view and create your own animation.